# TextBox is not showing new value in code-behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a asp:TextBox. its disabled. but its values is changed via javascript. When i click a button to get the updated value in that textbox it always show me empty ("").
In my Page_Load i am doing everything in if(!Page.IsPostBack) so there is no chance of updating TextBox value on postback in Page_Load.

Where i could be wrong? how can i get updated value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabled textboxes are not posted back.

See: http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t360866-textbox-no-value-if-disabled.html

Soultion: use a hidden or readonly field.

Comment: somehow in my case, it works when it is disabled and it doesnt work when it is read only. I have changed the textbox value through javascript too

Answer (score 0):

When you disable a control it's value is not send back in the postback. You should change the textbox to be readonly.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: Set your textbox readonly instead of making it disabled.

Solution 2: If you really have to disable the textbox, you can add an asp:hiddenfield to record the text in the textbox, you can get the value at server side then.